# Class difficulties in python programming

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is an example of my code, I have a file containing:

```
   Teams  Won   Loss
   arsenal 0     0
  liverpool0     0
  Manchester0    0
```

I have since before used `data[j][i]` to navigate throught my file where `j = row, i= column`.

I am trying to implement a class into my code, attributes that descibe if the team won or loss. Where I link these attributes to their placement in the column as for example:

```
self.lost= data[h][1] where h stands for the hometeam.
```

then instead of using the `data[h][1] += 1` in the `def hemmalag_bortalag` I want to somehow use the attributes to change it to ex ---> h.won

## Code

```
class Lag:
def __init__(self,won,lost):
    self.won = int(won)
    self.lost = int(lost)
 
    def won(self):
    self.won +=1
    self.won = data[h][1]


    def lost(self):
    self.lost +=1
    lost = data[h][2]

def hemmalag_bortalag(data):
print(" 1. Arsenal \n 2. Man Utd \n 3. Liverpool \n 4. Newcastle")
h(self) = int(input("Hometeam?\n"))
b(self) = int(input("Awayteam?\n"))
while b!= h:
    hx = int(input("how many goals did the hometeam do?\n"))
    bx = int(input("how many goals did the awayteam do\n"))
    
    if hx > bx:
        print("Hometeam won!")
        
        data[h][1] +=1 #------> h.won
        data[b][2] +=1 #-------> b.lost

    elif hx < bx:
        print("Awateam won!")
        data[b][2] +=1 #-----> b.won
        data[h][2] +=1 #------> h.lost

    elif hx == bx:
        print("Tie!")

    print("List is now updated!")
    b=h

def mata_in_resultat(): 
with open('Premier_League.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = [[line.strip().split()[0]] + [int(value) for value in 
line.strip().split()[1:]] for line in f ] 
    f.seek(0)
    hemmalag_bortalag(data)
    f.write('\n'.join((' '.join(map(str, line)) for line in data)))
    f.truncate()
```

The code just doesn't work with wrongmessages like `h is not defined` and `int object has no attribute "won"`

Comment: it's difficult to get the purpose of the class Lag, you don't use it in this code.

Comment: as you see in the #h.won/b.lost I want to implement them

Comment: your indentation is wrong on multiple spots, and you need `:` after `while b!= h`. Other than that what is `data`.. is it a global variable because it doesn't exist in the class but you still reference it there?

Comment: yeah I updated the code, data is defined in `def mata_in_resultat()`

Comment: but if I reference data in the attributes, do I somehow need to have data as an attribute itself?